# How to display popup only for first login

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, facebook-login

I am implementing login with facebook using javascript SDK.
Now in my code i have 3 different JS files
1. content.js and 2. FacebookLogin.js 3. popup.js
In my code there is anchor tag and onclick action opens a popup with different login options like facebook, linkedin, googleplus, twitter. Among them I have integrated for facebook.
Now once i click on facebook, iFrame opens and asks for login creds, then i supplies those and able to login properly.
Now user is logged in and I dont want to display that popup again on click of anchor tag. This means I want it to display only when user is not logged in.
Once the user is logged in and if i click on that link it should not open up that popup.

CODE:

content.js

```
function includeScripts(){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var host = "192.168.1.6";
    var server = "http://" + host + ":8080/OtherDomain/";

    // load Popup.js
    var popupJs = document.createElement("script");
    popupJs.type = 'text/javascript';
    popupJs.src = server + "js/Popup.js?_=" + new Date();
    head.appendChild(popupJs);

    // load FacebookLogin.js
    var facebookJs = document.createElement("script");
    facebookJs.type = 'text/javascript';
    facebookJs.src = server + "js/FacebookLogin.js?_=" + new Date();
    head.appendChild(facebookJs);

    // load GooglePlusLogin.js
    var googlePlusJs = document.createElement("script");
    googlePlusJs.type = 'text/javascript';
    googlePlusJs.src = server + "js/GooglePlusLogin.js?_=" + new Date();
    head.appendChild(googlePlusJs);

    var styleSheet = document.createElement('link');
    styleSheet.href = server + 'css/mpw.css?' + new Date();
    styleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
    head.appendChild(styleSheet);       
}



function onClickLoginPopup (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = this.href;    

    var guid = this.attributes.getNamedItem("GUID"); 

    var mainPopup = document.getElementById('popupMain');   

    if( mainPopup == null ) {
        console.log(mainPopup);
    } 
    else 
    {
        showSocialLoginPopup();     
    }

    return false;
}

function addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag() {

    var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];

        var guid = anchor.attributes.getNamedItem('GUID');
        if(guid)
        {
            anchor.addEventListener("click", onClickLoginPopup);
        }
    }   
}


function mpwInit() {

    addPopupContents();
    addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag();
}

includeScripts();
window.onload = mpwInit;
```

This is the facebook javascript:

```
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) 
  {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook. 
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      //alert(response.status + "Please log into this app");
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } 
    else 
    {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
    //  alert(response.status + "Please log into Facebook");
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() 
  {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
  {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                            // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
      {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

  };

  function Logout()
  {
      FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
  }



  function fblogin()
  { 
   FB.login(function(response){
       console.log('FB.login response',response); 

       checkLoginState();
   });
   return false;
  }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

My popup.js code:

```
function showSocialLoginPopup() {
    document.getElementById('popupMain').style.display = 'block';
}
function hidePopup() {
    document.getElementById('popupMain').style.display = 'none';
}

function addPopupContents() {

    var mainPopup = document.getElementById('popupMain');   
    if (mainPopup == null ) {

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.body.innerHTML += xmlhttp.response;                
            }
        };      
        xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/OtherDomain/popup.html', false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}

// To detect escape button
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
 evt = evt || window.event;
 if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
     hidePopup();
 }
};
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

That´s what [getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) is for, to check if the user is already autzorized and to refresh the user session/token. You should **only use it on page load** (right after FB.init) and just store the status (or the User ID) in a JS variable. Example code is in the docs.

For example:

```
var userID;

window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({
        ...
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //user is authorized
            userID = response.authResponse.userID;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
        }
    });
};
```

Here´s an article about the whole login process:

http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: i have added some code, should be easy to understand. but i suggest reading the blogpost i added, it offers a lot of useful information about the whole login process.

Comment: of course that´s only one way to solve it, and you can also store the user ID with localstorage. but that would be pointless imho, you need to use getLoginStatus on every page load anyway. you can´t be sure the user session is still valid by only checking out the localstorage, and getLoginStatus refreshes the user session.

Comment: well, you can remove a LOT of your code, for example, that large statusChangeCallback function. it´s just an example code to understand the concept. of course we don´t program for you on stackoverflow, we try to help you solve it on your own ;) - it´s really easy once you understand how it works.

Comment: just 1 small question. How can i use that variable(userId) in another js file.

Comment: if it´s not in a function closure, you can use it everywhere else too. there are some good books and tutorials about javascript scopes, very important to know as web developer.

Comment: I am using that as it is in another JS but getting undefined.

Comment: Basically I am a backend developer thats why struggling with this

Comment: then make sure that other js file gets included AFTER the one with the variable definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74680/discussion-between-mahendrakawde-and-luschn).

Comment: sorry, no time for chatting :) - but if you want to program frontend stuff, you will have to learn javascript or hire a frontend developer. those are the very basics, we´re happy to help on stackoverflow when you got stuck but it´s not place to get your work done for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a local variable to Browsers Storage and check its value before displaying your Login-Dialog.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "1");
//Retrieve
var value = localStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
```

If your User needs to relogin everytime the Browsers closes, than i would use **sessionStorage** instead.

Comment: Set localeStorage in function **statusChangeCallback** on status == 'connected'. And check the variable on the **onClick** function of your anchor tag.